# Hydrodynamic force in complex form for fluid structure interaction

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, complex-numbers, phase-space

I am studying force being acted from a viscous fluid surrounding a cantilever cylindrical rod, the rod is vibrating and its velocity causes the fluid around it to flow in the plane perpendicular to rod's longitudinal axis.

Velocity of cylinder is  [image: formula]

For small amplitudes the motion can be linearized and using streamline-vorticity equation, solution for streamline function is obtained, this helps writing velocity in the viscous fluid around cylinder.

Now, the circumferential integration of the stress gives the hydrodynamic force and it's in complex form.

$$\tau_{rr}=-\dot p+2\frac{\partial\dot \nu}{\partial r}, \tau_{r\theta}=(\frac{\partial\dot w}{\partial r}+\frac{\dot w}{r} +\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial\dot \nu}{\partial \theta})$$
 $$F=\int_0^{2\pi} (\tau_{rr}|_{r-a} cos\theta-\tau_{r\theta}|_{r-a}sin\theta)ad\theta$$
$$G=\int_0^{2\pi} (\tau_{rr}|_{r-a}sin\theta+\tau_{r\theta}|_{r-a}cos\theta)ad\theta$$

The paper further extends to the added  mass factor and the damping factor. Above calculated force comes out to be in complex form and its Real component is attributed to added mass and the Imaginary one for damping factor.

I can't understand how did we know that real component is affecting with the added mass effect and it is not other way around with imaginary part.
Also, if there is a concept of phase shift involved for the hydrodynamic force (as it is in complex form), then the phase is relative to what here? velocity of cylinder? or just the highest peak of the force?

Reference: [Added Mass and Damping of a Vibrating Rod in Confined Viscous Fluids 
S. S. Chen et al.](https://bit.ly/3aCE9Hq)

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting mathematical expressions.

Comment: The reference is behind a paywall that isn't accessible through my university's VPN.

Comment: @probably_someone there are ways around it, if you want to read, just google 'libgen' for help.